# (THREE.js) Material isn't working on my custom THREE.Geometry shape

Tags: colors, three.js, geometry

I created a triangle and I am trying to make it red. However it remains black. The problem doesn't seem to be the material as it works on other Geometries I've made.

Here is my triangle:

```
var triangle = new THREE.Geometry();
triangle.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(-10,10,0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-10,-10,0),
    new THREE.Vector3(10,-10,0)
    );
 triangle.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
 triangle.computeBoundingSphere();


 this.redtriangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangle, this.redMat)
```

I tried some suggestions online to color it using:

```
triangle.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
triangle.faces[0].vertexColors[0] = new THREE.Color(0xFF0000);
triangle.faces[0].vertexColors[1] = new THREE.Color(0xFF0000);
triangle.faces[0].vertexColors[2] = new THREE.Color(0xFF0000);
```

My material

```
    this.redMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({
    color: 0xFF0000,
    shading:THREE.FlatShading,
    // I added this line for the suggestion above
    // vertexColors:THREE.VertexColors,
    side:THREE.DoubleSide
})
```

I've also tried to insert

```
triangle.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

or

```
geometry.colorsNeedsUpdate = true;
```

but no matter what variations/where I put it, it doesn't want to work. The triangle stays black.

Answer (score 0):

Your vertices definition is in clockwise order when it should have been counter-clockwise. So if you change your `new THREE.Face3(0,1,2)` to `new THREE.Face3(0,2,1)` you should see something.